# OpenVSwitch OF1.4 Handle ARP as Normal L2/3 switch with RYU rest api

Tags: openflow

I want my OVS (which runs with OpenFlow14) to add flow entries for ARP with using the [Ryu REST API](http://ryu.readthedocs.io/en/latest/app/ofctl_rest.html). These ARP packets should be handled like a normal L2/3 switch.

Setup of my bridge `br0`:

`sudo ifconfig eth1 0
sudo ifconfig eth2 0
sudo ifconfig eth4 0
sudo ovs-vsctl add-br br0
sudo ovs-vsctl add-port br0 eth2
sudo ovs-vsctl add-port br0 eth4
sudo ovs-vsctl add-port br0 eth1
sudo ovs-vsctl set bridge br0 protocols=OpenFlow14
sudo ifconfig br0 192.168.101.1/24 up`

Now, I want to add flow entries for ARP with the hexcode `0xfffffffa` for normal actions referring to [OpenFlow 1.4 Specifications](https://www.opennetworking.org/images/stories/downloads/sdn-resources/onf-specifications/openflow/openflow-spec-v1.4.0.pdf#page=47):

`curl -X POST -d '{
"dpid":16267930820426,
"priority": 1,
    "match":{
        "eth_type":2054,
        "in_port":3
    },
    "actions":[
        {
        "type":"OUTPUT",
        "port":0xfffffffa
        }
    ]
}' http://localhost:8080/stats/flowentry/add`

However, it just sets flow entries with action drop:

`cookie=0x0, duration=281.451s, table=0, n_packets=0, n_bytes=0, priority=1,arp,in_port=3 actions=drop`

It worked well when using OpenFlow10 (when using the adequate hex code). But I need to switch to OpenFlow14.

I also tried using the string `NORMAL` as output port, but it did not work.
Does anyone have an idea what is going wrong?